# Cannot merge lists from two yamls in Spring Boot

Tags: list, spring-boot, merge, yaml

I've got a product config and two Spring profiles (`business` and `custom`).
Product config contains product constants (`briefCode`, `systemId` and so on).
`Business` profile is a part of the application itself and is common between `local`, `development`, `test` and `production` environments.
`Custom` profile is a test suite for our testers to enhance `business` profile with some features only relevant to `test` environment.

Here goes the problem. Say, here is the fragment of `application-business.yml` (which is embedded into every deployment):

```
PRODUCT_CODE1:
  - { name: briefCode, value: '0001' }
  - { name: systemId, value: ABC }
```

and here is the fragment of `application-custom.yml` (which is only present on the `test` environment where our logins are missing and we have to hardcode one):

```
PRODUCT_CODE1:
  - { name: login, value: hardcodedLogin }
```

In this situation I have only `login` field in the final configuration on the `test` environment.
So I would have to duplicate `briefCode` and `systemId` fields in `application-custom.yml`
But if I do that and after that `systemId` of `PRODUCT_CODE1` in `application-business.yml` is changed, say, to `BCD`, there will be an inconsistency on the `test` environment, since final configuration will contain old `systemId=ABC` value.

That is the problem I have with duplicating list content that cannot be merged.

My another way to solve this problem was to use `Map<String, ?>` instead of `List<?>`.

But here goes another issue (and no less counter-intuitive than the first one): some of product's properties start with two hashes (`##`) and some of them contain dots (`.`).
And Spring deals with them weirdly.

```
PRODUCT_CODE1:
  '##key1': value1
  "##key2': value2
  'k.e.y3': value3
  "k.e.y4": value4
```

And this is the `Map` of `PRODUCT_CODE1`: `key1=value1, key2=value2`.
Brilliant! Hashes dropped. Keys with dots inside omitted.
And despite single and double quotes!

Are there any other ways to solve my problem that I might not have thought of?

Am I missing anything? Am I doing anything wrong?

Please guide me then.

Thank in advance!

Regards, L.B.

Comment: The Spring config is a technical configuration; I don't think this kind of business domain information belongs there at all.

Comment: daniu, there is also a business requirement to be able to quickly change these product constants on the `production` environment without having to build and deploy new version of application. Hence, no hardcode in java code. And no database as well since our application is a stateless one. That's why we are limited to use this design.